# Unable to detect KeyPress event for Enter key

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keypress

I am trying to use the KeyPress event in VB.NET 2008, but it is not working.  Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this code?  This message box does not appear and the my status from my DB doesn't either.  The program says that it is OK, but it isn't working.

```
If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
    tblLogin = Proses.ExecuteQuery("Select * From TblUser where kode_user = '" & KdUserTxt.Text & "'")
    If tblLogin.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Kode User Not Found!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        KdUserTxt.Focus()
    Else
        StatusTxt.Text = tblLogin.Rows(0).Item("status")
        PswTxt.Focus()
    End If
End If
```

Comment: How did you add your KeyPress event to your TextBox ?

Comment: Holy Sql Injection vulnerability, Batman!

Comment: To follow up on the prior comment: _Please_ don't using string concatenation like that to build you're queries. What if I put something like `'DROP TABLE TblUser;--` in your KdUserTxt box?

Comment: so what must i do? im newbie here please ur help ..

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using the `KeyPress` event to capture control keys like the enter key.  You should, instead, be using the `KeyDown` event.  The `KeyDown` allows you to capture any physical key on the keyboard.  For instance:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

However, the normal way to accomplish something like this would be to add a button to your form such as an OK or a Submit button.  Then, in the properties of your form, set the `AcceptButton` property to that button.  Then, the WinForm framework will automatically call that button's click event for you when the user presses the Enter key.  Similarly, the `CancelButton` property sets which button is clicked when the user presses the Escape key.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to capture the **Enter** key **KeyDown** event, if you have set the **AcceptButton** property of your **WinForm**.

Set the property **AcceptButton** of the needed WinForm to **none** in order to make your code work.